# how to read function type signatures in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

given a function that adds one to Int, we can see its type signature:

```
Prelude> addOne :: Int -> Int; addOne x = x + 1
Prelude> :t addOne
addOne :: Int -> Int
```

the signature means addOne takes an Int and returns an Int. simple enough. instead if we define a function without specifying a type:

```
Prelude> anotherAddOne x = x + 1
Prelude> :t anotherAddOne
anotherAddOne :: Num a => a -> a
```

it makes sense that now we are dealing with `Num` not `Int` but whats the way to read `Num a => a -> a`? and what is the difference between `=>` and `->` here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
anotherAddOne :: Num a => a -> a
```

The `=>` here separates a class constraint and a type. In this example, `Num a` is the class constraint, which consists of a class `Num` and a type variable `a`. The full signature declares that for any type `a` that is a `Num`, the function `anotherAddOne` has the type `a -> a`.